# Discrete color code in color bar in matplotlib for displaying raster classes?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to use different color boxes (like legends) to show different classes in python instead of colorbar as shown below.
Here each color shows a different class, which is not being conveyed properly using colorbar. How to use different color codes as we do in legend?

[image]

I tried to set the number of colors in the color bar to 15. I have 8 classes range from 0 to 14.

> [0, 4, 5, 8, 10, 12, 13, 14]
>
> ['Water', 'Deciduous Broadleaf Forest', 'Mixed Forest', 'Woody Savannas', 'Grasslands', 'Croplands', 'Urban and Built-Up', 'Cropland/natural vegetation mosaic']

How to set a proper color bar.
Below, is how I am creating the colorbar.

```
m.imshow(data, cmap = plt.get_cmap('summer', 15))
cb = m.colorbar(location='right', format='%s', label='LULC')    
cb.set_ticks([0, 4, 5, 8, 10, 12, 13, 14])
cb.set_ticklabels(['Water', 'Deciduous Broadleaf Forest', 'Mixed Forest', 'Woody Savannas', 'Grasslands', 'Croplands', 'Urban and Built-Up', 'Cropland/natural vegetation mosaic'])
```